# Проблема запуска приложения: JNI error has occurred

Tags: java, spring, maven

Приложение работающее в IDE не запускается с `java -jar oasis.jar` так как будто ошибка в `pom.xml` хотя вроде все указано верно. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться. Дело вероятно в том, что `Spring` требует что ему укажут `main`, но  `<transformer>...` ему не подходит, а что подходит? При этом у меня не Boot так что `@SpringBootApplication` мне не подходит.

`pom.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.oasis</groupId>
    <artifactId>oasis</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>3.0</version>

    <build>
        <finalName>oasis</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>org.oasis.Application</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <testResources>
            <testResource>
                <directory>src/test/java/resources</directory>
            </testResource>
        </testResources>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <spring-version>4.3.9.RELEASE</spring-version>
        <logback.version>1.0.10</logback.version>
        <slf4j.version>1.7.3</slf4j.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.guava/guava -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
            <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
            <version>23.5-jre</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-math3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>13.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.18</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jul-to-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-access</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-beans -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.mail/mail -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.lightbody.bmp/browsermob-core-littleproxy -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.lightbody.bmp</groupId>
            <artifactId>browsermob-core-littleproxy</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.0-beta-6</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Падает так как будто Manifest не указан, хотя все указано:

> pavel$ java -jar oasis.jar  Error: A JNI error has occurred, please
>   check your installation and try again Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.SecurityException: Invalid signature file digest for
>   Manifest main attributes  at
>   sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.processImpl(SignatureFileVerifier.java:284)
>     at
>   sun.security.util.SignatureFileVerifier.process(SignatureFileVerifier.java:238)
>     at java.util.jar.JarVerifier.processEntry(JarVerifier.java:316)     at
>   java.util.jar.JarVerifier.update(JarVerifier.java:228)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.initializeVerifier(JarFile.java:383)    at
>   java.util.jar.JarFile.getInputStream(JarFile.java:450)    at
>   sun.misc.URLClassPath$JarLoader$2.getInputStream(URLClassPath.java:940)
>     at sun.misc.Resource.cachedInputStream(Resource.java:77)    at
>   sun.misc.Resource.getByteBuffer(Resource.java:160)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:454)  at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)    at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)    at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)    at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)     at
>   sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:495)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ошибка "Invalid signature file digest for Manifest main attributes" переводится как "Неверная подпись манифеста", если по простому. А происходит это из-за того, что один из jar-файлов, которые вы пытаетесь объединить, имеет цифровую подпись, которая в новом jar-файле перестаёт быть действительной.

Помочь должно исключение из сборки файлов, отвечающих за подписи:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.3</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shade</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <transformers>
                   <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                       <mainClass>org.oasis.Application</mainClass>
                   </transformer>
               </transformers>
               <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Или ручное удаление их из jar-файла

```
zip -d <fat jar file name>.jar META-INF/*.RSA META-INF/*.DSA META-INF/*.SF
```

Comment: очень интересно, спасибо, никогда бы не подумал что дело в цифровой подписи. А как-же мне решить эту проблему. Надо поднимать приложение, вроде все работает в IDE, а на стенд не залить. Может быть вы еще подскажите как мне это поправить?